# Mongoose - Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"[object Object]\" at path \"responsavel\"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, restangular

I am new to the MEAN stack and been studying it for the past 3 days.

I get this error when I try to save a new object with a one-to-may relationship. I am using restangular + mongoose and can't find the origin of the error.

Here's the save I'm doing when a form is submitted:

```
$scope.saveProjeto = function() {
  console.log($scope.projeto);
  Projeto.post($scope.projeto).then(function() {
    $location.path('/projetos');
  });
};
```

Here's my User Model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
Schema = mongoose.Schema,
relationship = require('mongoose-relationship');

// Creating Schema
var UserSchema = Schema({
  nome: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  sobrenome: {
    type: String,
    required: false
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  projetos: [{
    type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "Projeto"
  }]
});

// Exporting Model Schema
module.exports = UserSchema;
```

Here's my Projeto model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Schema = mongoose.Schema,
relationship = require('mongoose-relationship');

// Creating Schema
var ProjetoSchema = Schema({
  nome: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  responsavel: {
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: "User",
    required: true
  },
  descricao: {
    type: String
  },
  data_inicio: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
  },
  data_fim_prevista: {
    type: Date,
  },
  data_fim: {
    type: Date,
  },
  created_at: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
  },
  updated_at: {
    type: Date,
    required: true
  }
});
```

And this is what I get on the console:

```
message: "Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[object Object]" at path 

"responsavel""
name: "CastError"
path: "responsavel"
type: "ObjectId"
value: {_id: "5553afb5d65550216c26d69f", nome: "Renato", sobrenome: "Correa", email: "renatojf2@gmail.com",…}
__v: 0
_id: "5553afb5d65550216c26d69f"
email: "foobar@gmail.com"
fromServer: true
nome: "Renato"
parentResource: null
password: "foobar"
projetos: []
reqParams: null
restangularCollection: false
restangularized: true
route: "users"
sobrenome: ""
```

Comment: Try to change  ref: 'User' in responsavel to ref: 'UserSchema'

Comment: Try changing `type: Schema.ObjectId` to `type: Schema.Types.ObjectId`. for `responsavel` field.

Comment: Tried both options and didn't make any difference.. same error :(

Comment: Your user is exporting the schema, not the model (eg:`mongoose.model('User', UserSchema)`). That's probably a mistake. I'm also not sure if you're creating the Projeto model or if you are using `mongoose-relationship`. If so, can you post your full model files?

Comment: sorry for the late response.. been busy with other things here.. I am using mongoose-relationship.. Those are my full model files.